# (min-width:1110px) affecting whole styles

Tags: css, media-queries

The styles are made with mobile first structure. So the main styles, made for up to 360px width devices, have no media query. The desktop styles are wrapped into a 1110px min-width media query, but they are affecting the whole page style. When I check the styles with Chrome Inspector, they don't even show the media query...

Here's the link of the file: http://www.institutopsicode.com/wp/wp-content/themes/psicode/style.css

You can see the problem at this URL: http://www.institutopsicode.com/wp/2015/08/31/tu-mente-te-miente/

The sidebar is being shown at the bottom of the mobile version, while in the main styles for 360px devices it has a display:none;

I've tried many things and orders but still doesn't make what I need it to...

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: Please create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example as a code snippet or on JSfiddle. Linking to external sites is highly discouraged due to possibility of link rot.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where it has styles for when the page is at 360px

Comment: Hm... I wonder what a backslash at the end of a line does in CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It was just a curly bracket that I would never discover at line 1207...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is for the `#sidebar {display:block}` part to be inside the  media query for `min-width:1110px`, you have a problem.
There is a `}` that ends the media query in line 1208, but the code that says `#sidebar {display:block}` is in line 1335, outside of any media query.

There is also an extraneous `}` in line 1600, so I think you should remove the one at line 1208.

Comment: Oh God... thank you so much man cocoa! I was getting really MAD with this... and of course is a curly bracket -__- Can you tell me hoy did you discover the error?? Is there any tool??

Comment: No specific tool, but you said that the media query didn't even show up. So I started out from the assumption that the media query was problematic. And although it looked like the `{display:block}` was in the query (judging by the indentation), it really wasn't. That's where the editor's "Move to matching bracket" command came in...

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the page and check out the css, there are these two blocks of code:

```
//line 1335
//media="all"
#sidebar {
  width: 260px;
  margin-top: 31px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

//line 629
//media="all"
#sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

So as you can see the browser is not capturing the specified media query. Could be happening from what Mr Lister says